# Force the unloading of a kernel module when the USB devices is unplugged?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, udev

I'm using a [MultiTech GPRS modem](http://www.multitech.com/en_US/PRODUCTS/Families/MultiModemGPRS/) on Ubuntu 8.0.4 (2.6.24-24 kernel with the MultiTech patches to the ti_usb_3410_5052 module).

The device works great.  However if I disconnect it and then reconnect without removing the module in between, it hangs.  Attempting to `modprobe -r ti_usb_3410_5052` at this point hangs.  And running `lsusb` hangs.

So.  There must be a way to trigger the removal of the module when I disconnect the device.  Any hints?  Maybe a udev rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have you already tried just using rmmod to remove the module?
- Also, you should probably put the ppp device down before removing the hardware.
- If you want to create a udev rule that reacts on removing the driver, something like `DRIVER="ti_usb_4410_5052", ACTION="remove", PROGRAM="/sbin/rmmod ti_usb_3410_5052`.

Comment: Yes, everything works properly if I rmmod the module after unplugging the device.  The issue is one of automating...

There is no ppp device; I'm using the device as an SMS gateway.

I don't understand what would trigger that udev rule.  It almost looks like it's triggered by unloading the module, which doesn't seem to make sense.  What I'd like to see is a udev rule triggered by unplugging the USB device...

Comment: It seems that way; I haven't tried it yet, though. But other people have successfully used similar lines to be triggered when removing USB hardware, cf. http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-559014.html